# Cannot compile jetbrains intelij idea community edition on alpine linux

Tags: java, jdk, alpine-linux

Amazon JDK has an Alpine Linux version, and I downloaded JetBrains's IntelliJ community source code. The ant build stuck at `Failed to complete gradle setupJdks setupKotlinPlugin` and the JetbrainsRuntime compilation failed at

```
checking if custom source is suppressed (openjdk-only)... no
checking which variant of the JDK to build... normal
checking which debug level to use... release
checking which variants of the JVM to build... server client minimal core zero custom
configure: Unknown variant(s) specified: "server client minimal core zero custom"
configure: The available JVM variants are: "server client minimal core zero custom"
configure: error: Cannot continue
```

Is it possible to compile JetBrains IntelliJ community edition on Alpine against musl jdk?

Comment: I am trying to compile JetbrainsRuntime on alpine linux.